# Email with japanese characters in java

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I am using java to send emails. The message sent can be in different languages, but when I send it in Japanese, the received mail just have "???????" characters.

The code is something like this:

```
 String content = "\u30d5\u30a1\u30a4\u30eb\u540d:";    
SMTPMessage message = new SMTPMessage(sess);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress dests[] = new InternetAddress[]{ new InternetAddress(to) };
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, dests);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(content, "text/html");

            Transport.send(message);
```

The content sent are unicode characters. How should I encode correctly the message?

Comment: It seems to work with "message.setText(content, "UTF-8")". I couldn't use the setText method with 3 arguments.

Comment: If I can use only the setText method with 2 argument, which alternatives do I have?

Comment: I could resolved it with setContent(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8")

Answer (score 2):

You should use `setText` instead of `setContent`

```
message.setText( content, "UTF-8", "html" );
```

Comment: If I can use only the setText method with 2 argument, which alternatives do I have?

Comment: @Torque. 2-argument version creates a `text/plain` part.  If this is what you want, then go ahead and use it, the syntax should be `setText( content, "UTF-8" )`.  If, as in your original example, you need a text/html message, then you have to use the 3-argument variant.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:-
`message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: That solves only half the problem. The important thing is to make sure that all setXYZ() calls specify the encoding because otherwise you'll get the default plattform encoding (which may or may not be UTF8)! Also note that if the encoding is mostly used for eastern cultures, UTF-8 may (actually certainly - apart from compatibility) not be the best choice, so I wouldn't hardcode it.

Comment: @Voo - Good comments. Feel free to add an answer yourself since you seem fairly knowledgeable in this area.

Comment: @Voo: Unless CoolBeans is sending e-mails with multiple megabytes of text, or is sending hundreds/thousands of e-mails, the advantages gained from using UTF-8 (such as compatibility) over an Asian character set outweigh the increase in payload size, in my opinion.

Comment: @JAB: Actually, UTF-16 may be a better option in case of pure Japanese text, as each character will be represented by 2 bytes instead of 3 or 4 as is the case for UTF-8

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak: I suppose so. There are a couple other things about UTF-8 that may make it a better choice if size isn't your only concern, but if you're aiming for reducing size while still using a Unicode encoding, UTF-16 would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Apparently the emails are in many languages, in which case it's a no-brainer that he should use UTF-8. I send & receive emails and text in Japanese and always use UTF-8. Anything else will possibly waste someone's time trying to read it - maybe the recipient will end up writing an SO question right here, asking how to parse this non UTF-8 email he's receiving from this poster ;-) Also read the advantages compared to UTF-16 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Compared_to_UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your use of `setContent()`, try:

```
message.setText(content, "UTF-8", "html");
```

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You tried "ISO-2022-JP" encoding?

```
message.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=ISO-2022-JP");
message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP");
```