# Sending Japanese text in sms and email

Tags: java, android, smsmanager, cjk

I have a requirement to send the sms and email on the trigger of some event.
It's working fine when I am testing with english. But when I change the text to **Japanese**, it's producing some sort of junk message. I am using java as my programming language.

I have tried some solutions like changing the charset preference and adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`  in run configurations, but doesn't seem to work.

It's not working in a particular case.
When I hard-code the string in my java class as Japanese string then it's working fine. But when I try to read from property file it's producing some junk characters.

Comment: Here is the previous questions link  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271582/email-with-japanese-characters-in-java?rq=1" ;  it might be helpful..

Comment: For sending email, you need to set mimetype header something like this, mimeMessage.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); And for sending SMS typically you need to check the documentation of SMS service provider. Just by setting utf8 in headers sometimes doesn't work as it depends upon the server implementation

Comment: Property files are per default encoded in ISO8859-1. Did you escape the japanese characters? How did you read the property files?

Comment: @Henry : I am reading value from property file directly using "Value" annotation of spring

Comment: Then make sure the property files contain only ISO8859-1 characters. Use unicode escapes for the others. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/native2ascii.html to help with the conversion.

Comment: @Henry : or I can convert it to UTF?

Comment: There are some options available to tell spring to use another encoding for the property files (for example in the `@PropertySource` annotation). Do a little search, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks buddy. solved it. you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved this. As I have stated in my question itself, that the problem is mainly with reading from **.property** file. When I tried to hardcode the string it's working perfectly.

As @Henry suggested in his comments, all the .property files  contain only `ISO8859-1` characters. So, I followed the process to convert string from I`SO8859-1 format to UTF.`
It can be achieved by simply using this one line of code.

```
String utf8String = new String(Charsets.ISO_8859_1.encode("your string").array()).
```

Although, It solved my purpose, But I thought it's not a clean way to solve this.
For my scenario I had to add a new configuration, so instead of going through above way. I kept the string in separate text file and read from the file.

```
        String filePath = "filename.txt"
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("file not found ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred ", e);
        }
```

It solved the issue without using any hack to convert from one CharSet to another.